# (Backwards/Forwards) DOM navigation on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm attempting to move the coin class to the appropriate element on keydown.
However I'm not certain how to navigate the DOM tree correctly if the elements are similarly named. Also, I move up/down depending on keydown(e.which), but I need to rotate back to the top or bottom if the coin is in certain places.

Say for example I press 'down' when the bottom section has the coin class. I need to move the coin to the top section. Adversely pressing 'up' on the top section would find the last section. Normal up/down behavior on other elements.

**EDIT:** I have come up with an almost complete solution(Below), but can't figure out why it's running my function twice on keydown (proved with logs), it works in certain cases, but not in others.  A note, I have also added `data-number` values to appropriate divs. Eg. `data-number="1"`

```
$('div[id=menu-item]').mouseover(function (e) {
    $('.coin').removeClass('coin InsideContent active');
    $(e.target).prev().show();
    $(e.target).prev().addClass('active InsideContent coin');
});

$(window).on('keydown', function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    var direction;
    switch (key) {

        case 40:
            direction = 'down'
            findNextTarget(direction);

        case 38:
            direction = 'up';
            findNextTarget(direction);
    }
});

function findNextTarget(direction) {
    var target;
    var classes = $('.coin').data('number');
    console.log(classes);
    switch (classes) {
        case 1:
            if (direction == 'down') {
                target = $('*[data-number="2"]');
            } else if (direction == 'up') {
                target = $('*[data-number="3"]');
            }
        case 2:
            if (direction == 'down') {
                target = $('*[data-number="3"]');
            } else if (direction == 'up') {
                target = $('*[data-number="1"]');
            }
        case 3:
            if (direction == 'down') {
                target = $('*[data-number="1"]');
            } else if (direction == 'up') {
                target = $('*[data-number="2"]');
            }
    }

    $('.coin').removeClass('coin InsideContent active');
    target.show();
    target.addClass('active InsideContent coin');
};
```

I've tried multiple routes, but I'm not winning.
I'm thinking a switch statement and then an if/else to check which if the 'coin' class is currently at the top or bottom and needs to rotate around. I'm just struggling with the DOM navigation.

There's probably an easier way to do this with an unordered list, but I really need to learn more about DOM tree navigation.

**My menu items:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="block">
        <div id="pane">
            <div id="coiner" class="one active InsideContent coin" style=""></div>
            <div id="menu-item" class="InsideContent">New Game
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pane">
            <div id="coiner" class="two inactive InsideContent" style="display:none;"></div>
            <div id="menu-item" class="InsideContent">Options
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pane">
            <div id="coiner" class="three inactive InsideContent" style="display:none;"></div>
            <div id="menu-item" class="InsideContent">Exit
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Jquery code that moves the coin on hover:**

```
$('div[id=menu-item]').mouseover(function (e) {
    $('.coin').removeClass('coin InsideContent active');
    $(e.target).prev().show();
    $(e.target).prev().addClass('coin InsideContent active');
});
```

**The keys I need to check(e.which)**

> down = 40 | up = 38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally working.
I was missing `break` statements after my switch cases, which was causing weird behaviour. `break` is you friend.

While my solution isn't really scalable, it does solve the immediate problem.

**Working Code:**

```
$('div[id=menu-item]').mouseover(function (e) {
    $('.coin').removeClass('coin InsideContent active');
    $(e.target).prev().show();
    $(e.target).prev().addClass('active InsideContent coin');
});

$(window).on('keydown', function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    switch (key) {
        case 40:
            findNextTarget('down');
            break;
        case 38:
            findNextTarget('up');
            break;
    }
});

function findNextTarget(direction) {
    var target;
    var dataNumber = $('.coin').data('number');
    switch (dataNumber) {
        case 1:
            if (direction == 'down') {
                target = $('*[data-number="2"]');
            } else if (direction == 'up') {
                target = $('*[data-number="3"]');
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (direction == 'down') {
                target = $('*[data-number="3"]');
            } else if (direction == 'up') {
                target = $('*[data-number="1"]');
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (direction == 'down') {
                target = $('*[data-number="1"]');
            } else if (direction == 'up') {
                target = $('*[data-number="2"]');
            }
            break;
    }
    $('.coin').removeClass('coin InsideContent active');
    target.show();
    target.addClass('active InsideContent coin');
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.menu-item').mouseover(function(e) {
  $('.coiner').removeClass('coin').hide();
  $(this).prev().addClass('coin').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pane">
  <div class="coiner" style="">pane 1</div>
  <div class="menu-item InsideContent">New Game
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pane">
  <div class="coiner" style="display:none;">pane 2</div>
  <div class="menu-item InsideContent">Options
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pane">
  <div class="coiner" style="display:none;">pane 3</div>
  <div class="menu-item InsideContent">Exit
  </div>
</div>
```